# Problems with waiting for the threads to end

Tags: c#, multithreading, join

I'm doing some C# threading. No problems starting the threads and transferring data to them, but I have a problem with waiting for them to end.

My code is shown below. I'm using `Join()` to wait for the threads to end, but for some reason my code doesn't work.

The main thread (i.e. the for loop) isn't blocked despite calling `Join()` on all the active threads.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
List<Thread> calculationThreads = new List<Thread>();

foreach (string calculation in calculations)
{
    if (calculationThreads.Count < 5)
    {
        Thread calculationThread = new Thread(DoCalculation);
        calculationThreads.Add(calculationThread);

        calculationThread.Start(threadData);
    }
    else
    {
        // Wait for the threads to complete
        foreach (Thread calculationThread in calculationThreads)
        {
            calculationThread.Join();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are sure the calculation threads haven't all terminated?

Comment: Have you considered using the task parallel library to handle your threading rather than doing it explicitly like this?  A lot of helpful methods to make your life a bit easier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Comment: I think you should remove threads from CalculationThreads collection after joining.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not blocking at all?  Looks to me like it would block fine for the first 5 calculations, but since you never remove a completed calculation from the list, after that it would just race right through.

Comment: why does your code "not work"?

Comment: 'I'm using Join() to wait for the threads to end' - first mistake.  Do look at TPL as posted by @Paddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is your handling of the `else` case. If there is already five threads the code will wait for the threads to finish, but the task that it was trying to add is never added. It will just throw away that task and go on to the next.

The second problem is that you don't remove any threads from the list, so once it reaches five threads, it will wait forever. If the first problem didn't discard the rest of the tasks, your program would just lock up.

Also, you are wasting processing time by waiting for all five threads to finish before continuing the work, but that's a smaller problem.

Comment: There is a waste of processing time yes, but if there are any dependencies in the data that is produced by the threads, the sequence should wait after the for loop.

Comment: @StianStandahl: Yes, when the last task is dealt to a thread you have to wait for all treads to finish before using the result, that's inevitable. The current code would however chop up the tasks in groups of five, and get that waste for every group.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for some approach where I just calculate how many threads I've started and in the end of each thread I decrease the counter.

Then in the beginning of your loop you can have

```
while(counter >= 5)
{
//Wait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a while loop that waits for all the threads to end.

```
List<Thread> calculationThreads = new List<Thread>();

foreach (string calculation in calculations)
{
    if (calculationThreads.Count < 5)
    {
        Thread calculationThread = new Thread(DoCalculation);
        calculationThreads.Add(calculationThread);

        calculationThread.Start(threadData);
    }
    else
    {
        // Wait for the threads to complete
        while(calculationThread.Any(x => x.IsAlive)){}
        // Clearing the list
        calculationThread.Clear();
    }   
}
```

If you want to keep the threads for after the for loop you should have another list for storing the threads.

Comment: Ouch. You should definitely not have a busy loop waiting for the threads to finish.

Comment: i know. should probably have a timeout function somewhere in there ;)

Answer (score 0):

How many calculations are you providing to the method?

Reading the code, if you provide 4 calculations you'll start 4 threads but never actually go to the code where you do a thread.Join().

Move the thread.join loop outside the if else statement.

```
List<Thread> calculationThreads = new List<Thread>();

    foreach (string calculation in calculations)
    {
        if (calculationThreads.Count < 5)
        {
            Thread calculationThread = new Thread(DoCalculation);
            calculationThreads.Add(calculationThread);

            calculationThread.Start(threadData);
        }

    }
    foreach (Thread calculationThread in calculationThreads)
    {
        calculationThread.Join();
    }
```